# Cannot get element with the "display: none" property applied to it using getElementById()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, queryselector

I'm running into an issue where the `getElementById()` function is unable to get a particular element on the page that has the `display: none` property applied to it, even though it's visible  in the DOM (I can see that the div and its id exists on the final rendered page).

Is there a way around this?

Here's the code:

```
    togglePanel() {
        const panelId = this.accordionItem.querySelector("#collapsible-panel");

        this.shouldShowAccordion = !this.shouldShowAccordion;

        if (this.shouldShowAccordion) {
            panelId.classList.remove("collapsed");
        }
        else {
            panelId.classList.add("collapsed");
        }  
    }
```

"collapsible-panel" is the ID of the div which has `display: none` applied to it.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (escpecially because there's no `.getElementById()` call in your question)

Comment: Please add some demo on jsfiddle or somewhere, so that it can makes more sense.

Comment: My mistake. I'm actually using `querySelector()` on an HTMLElement node which contains the div with display: none property.

Comment: Then [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63086657/edit) your question

Answer (score 1):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("div[id='collapsiblepanel']").style.display = 'block';

}, 2000)
```

```css
#collapsiblepanel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

Following is ana example where I am selecting a div which has the value of display as none. After 2 seconds I am setting up it's display to block.
```

```html
<div id="collapsiblepanel">

</div>
```

Comment: Why an attribute selector and not a simple id selector? And how does this solve OPs problem?

Comment: @Andreas even if you change it to document.getElementById("collapsiblepanel") or document.querySelector("#collapsiblepanel")  it works.

Comment: Let's rephrase my comment: How is your answer relevant for OPs problem?

Comment: This is an example that I have given to select an element in JS even of it's display is none.

Comment: None of the `.getElement*` or `.querySelector*` methods care about the visibility of an element. As long as it is in the DOM and matches the id, class, tagname, selector, ... it will be found by those methods.